# “unable to find the specified executable file” when trying to use mpirun on julia

Tags: julia, mpi, openmpi, pbs, torque

I am trying to run my julia code on multiple nodes of a cluster, which uses Moab and Torque for the scheduler and resource manager.
In an interactive session where I requested 3 nodes, I load julia and openmpi modules and run:

```
mpirun -np 72 --hostfile $PBS_NODEFILE -display-allocation julia --project=.  "./estimation/test.jl"
```

The mpirun does successfully recognize my 3 nodes since it displays:

```
======================   ALLOCATED NODES   ======================
        comp-bc-0383: slots=24 max_slots=0 slots_inuse=0 state=UP
        comp-bc-0378: slots=24 max_slots=0 slots_inuse=0 state=UNKNOWN
        comp-bc-0372: slots=24 max_slots=0 slots_inuse=0 state=UNKNOWN
=================================================================
```

However, after that it returns an error message

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun was unable to find the specified executable file, and therefore
did not launch the job.  This error was first reported for process
rank 48; it may have occurred for other processes as well.

NOTE: A common cause for this error is misspelling a mpirun command
      line parameter option (remember that mpirun interprets the first
      unrecognized command line token as the executable).

Node:       comp-bc-0372
Executable: /opt/aci/sw/julia/1.5.3_gcc-4.8.5-ips/bin/julia
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What could be the possible cause of this? Is it because it has trouble accessing julia from other nodes?  (I think this is the case because the code runs as long as -np X where x <= 24, which is the number of slots for one node; as soon as x >= 25, it fails to run)

Comment: the executable (and its dependencies) must be available on **all** the nodes. So unless you are using a shared filesystem (such as NFS), you need to manually deploy the executable (and its dependencies) on all the nodes.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thanks again for the comment. I'm currently verifying the administrator on NFS. Sorry if I'm doing somehting silly, but I've also tried `ssh <other node> module load julia` before the `mpirun` command but it still does not work. How would you "manually deploy the executable"? Is it something related to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: Manually copy the binary and its dependencies to the local filesystem on all the nodes.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://hpc.uni.lu/old/users/howtos/UsingMPIstacksWithModules.html . In short, you should export the variables with `-x PATH -x LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and you can try if it worked with `which julia` instead of `julia [...] test.jl`

Comment: Thank you both. I tried @Oskar's method and it worked! I was also able to actually launch julia. It won't read my test.jl properly, but I think I should work a bit more on adding my julia working directory to both paths.

Comment: I'll write that as an answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a good manual how to work with modules and `mpirun`. UsingMPIstacksWithModules

To sum it up with what is written in the manual:

> It should be highlighted that modules are nothing else than a structured way to manage your environment variables; so, whatever hurdles there are about modules, apply equally well about environment variables.

What you need is to export the environment variables in your `mpirun` command with `-x PATH -x LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. To see if this worked you can then run

```
mpirun -np 72 --hostfile $PBS_NODEFILE -display-allocation -x PATH -x LD_LIBRARY_PATH which julia
```

Also, you should consider giving the whole path of the file you want to run, so `/path/to/estimation/test.jl` instead of `./estimation/test.jl` since your working directory is not the same in every node. (In general it is always safer to use whole paths).
By using whole paths, you should also be able to use `/path/to/julia` (that is the output of `which julia`) instead of only `julia`, this way you should not need to export the environment variables.